# Why doesn't Mozilla Firefox process correct jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a script that keeps the row title and column title of a large table visible while scrolling. Everything works fine in IE9, Google Chrome, Opera 11, but in Firefox 6, it' not working. The row titles are ok, but the column title (the headers) are messed up.

Here is the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/39/).

Here is the javascript:

```
function moveScroll() {
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scroll_left = $(window).scrollLeft();
    var anchor_top = $("#main_table").offset().top;
    var anchor_left = $("#main_table").offset().left;
    var anchor_bottom = $("#bottom_anchor").offset().top;

    $("#clone").find("thead").css({
        width: $("#main_table thead").width()+"px",
        position: 'absolute',
        left: - scroll_left  + 'px'
    });

    $("#main_table").find(".first").css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: scroll_left + anchor_left + 'px'
     });

if (scroll_top >= anchor_top && scroll_top <= anchor_bottom) {
    clone_table = $("#clone");
    if (clone_table.length == 0) {
        clone_table = $("#main_table")
            .clone()
            .attr('id', 'clone')
            .css({
                width: $("#main_table").width()+"px",
                position: 'fixed',
                pointerEvents: 'none',
                left: $("#main_table").offset().left+'px',
                top: 0
            })
            .appendTo($("#table_container"))
            .css({
                visibility: 'hidden'
            })
            .find("thead").css({
                visibility: 'visible'
            });
    }
}
else {
    $("#clone").remove();
}
}

$("#main_table")
    .wrap('<div id="table_container"></div>')
    .after('<div id="bottom_anchor"></div>');
$(window).scroll(moveScroll);
```

Is there any solution to this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from giving your "clone" table's `<thead>` element "position: absolute".  If you take that out, it works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

```
$("#clone").find("thead").css({
    width: $("#main_table thead").width()+"px",
    // position: 'absolute',                     <---- This is the problem
    left: - scroll_left  + 'px'
});
```

[Here is your modified fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/41/)

Comment: It's not working correct. Now if you scroll down, then right, the headers don't go any more to the left, but stay fixed.

Comment: Adding "position: 'fixed'" and "left: - scroll_left+anchor_left+'px'" solved the problem, although in Firefox it flickers unpleasant ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/42/)). Thanks for bringing into attention the position property.